# in TexformField , Null check operator used on a null value flutter

Tags: flutter, null, textformfield

```
 [my simple program][1]     class _MyHomePageState extends 
 State<MyHomePage> {
String? username;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
GlobalKey<FormState> formstate =
    new GlobalKey<FormState>(); 

 send() {
 
  var _formdate = formstate.currentState;

  if (_formdate!.validate()) {
    _formdate.save();
    print('valid');
    print('$username');
   } else {
    (print('not valid'));
    print('$username');
    }
   }
   return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    ),
    body: Form(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      key: formstate, 
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(onSaved: (text) {
            username = text;
          }, validator: (text) {
            if (text!.length <= 4) {
              return " text can not be equal or less than 4 characters";
            }
            if (text.length > 10) {
              return "maximum number is 10 characters";
            }
            return "you are correct";
          }),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              send();
            },
            child: const Text('send'),
          ),
         ],
       ),
      ),
     ),
    );
   }
  }
```

- after running , when i enter valid name and press send, it also gives null
  and not valid at console, and when remove null check(!) it gives error, don't know how to solve.
- tried to use currentstate.validate and same issue

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String username = "";
```

and if this does not work provide more detail on what are you trying to do.

Comment: The method 'validate' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'
The method 'save' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'
i got both of those errors when i remove ! before validate
i am trying to enter name in text form and after pressing send, and the validator check , it gives valid, it always print invalid and null value, although i enter valid name. it always keep giving null and invalid

Comment: i am trying to type name in text form field and then press send from button, if name is valid , it print valid and print the user name, i am trying to use validator , but it gives the above issues. and after adding ! before validate , it gives no error, but it always print invalid and null , although i entered valid user name

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`return "you are correct";`

write:

```
return null;
```